# Loading csv files with wildcards to match a pattern

Tags: regex, csv, apache-spark, filepath

I have 24 csv files that contain 0 to 23 in there name example hyper01.csv , hyper02.csv,....,hyper23.csv . But i just want to load files from 08 to 15 using wildcards

currently i am using folder_name/*{08-15} but its not working i am using spark

Comment: I am trying this folder_name/*{08,15}*.csv   whats the issue in it..also i need to load it using wildcard not any code

Answer (score 0):

if you are using scala you could try this:

```
  def getPaths(dir: String): List[String] = {
    val file = new File(dir)
    file.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
      .filter(_.getName.startsWith("hyper"))
      .filter(s=>{
        val index = s.getName.replace("hyper", "")
          .replaceFirst("0", "")
          .replaceAll("\\.(.*)","")
          .toInt
        index >= 8 && index <= 15
      })
      .map(_.getPath).toList
  }

  val filesDirectory = "C:\\Users\\user\\hyper"
  getPaths(filesDirectory).foreach(println(_))

  val df = spark.read.csv(getPaths(filesDirectory):_*)
```

output:

```
C:\Users\user\hyper\hyper08.csv
C:\Users\user\hyper\hyper15.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala small function can be used for get required files:

```
def getDirs(root: String, start: Int, end: Int): Seq[String] = {
  (start to end).map(v => f"$root/hyper$v%02d.csv")
}

// usage
spark.read.parquet(getDirs("folder_name", 8, 15): _*)
```